# Composer issue: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-6

I had already installed composer 1.9.0.
Then when I run " composer global require laravel/installer"
I got an error
 "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.2.0].
    - laravel/installer v2.2.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.

Comment: _laravel/installer v2.2.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system._

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a version that is generally compatible with your current framework.
Forexamlple ：

```
    composer global require laravel/installer ~1.2
```